# Use a varchar local variable in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL server for this query... I will be creating several SELECT statements which will utilize the same portion of a WHERE clause. So far, I have declared a vachar variable to include in the WHERE clause but I am receiving an error. This is what I have tried so far:

```
DECLARE @PersonalLoans varchar(500) = 'code = ''RTR'' OR 
code = ''RTL'' OR 
code = ''LRV'' OR 
code = ''LPV'' OR 
code = ''LN'' OR 
code = ''LFR'' OR 
code = ''LCV'''

DECLARE @L01 int = 0
SELECT @L01 = ROUND(SUM(balance)*-1,2) FROM loan WHERE @PersonalLoans AND paydue > @databasedate      
PRINT '"L01": ' + CAST(@L01 AS varchar(15)) + ';'
```

I am receiving an error at the WHERE clause:
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.

I've done some research and come across the EXEC function but I need to be able to add the "AND paydue > @databasedate" to the WHERE clause. I will need to use the @PersonalLoans variable several times and append different AND clauses to it throughout the query.

Comment: `code IN ('RTR', 'RTL', 'LRV', 'LPV', 'LN', 'LFR', 'LCV')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this won't work without anything like `EXECUTE` or similar.

But you're lucky here. These multiple `OR`s could be simplified to

```
code IN ('RTR',
         'RTL', 
         'LRV', 
         'LPV', 
         'LN', 
         'LFR', 
         'LCV')
```

. That follows that you could use a table variable you push your codes into and use it as the list for `IN`:

```
DECLARE @codes
        TABLE (code varchar(3));
INSERT INTO @codes
            VALUES ('RTR'),
                   ('RTL'), 
                   ('LRV'), 
                   ('LPV'), 
                   ('LN'), 
                   ('LFR'), 
                   ('LCV');

DECLARE @L01 int = 0;
SELECT @L01 = round(sum(balance) * -1, 2)
       FROM loan
       WHERE paydue > @databasedate
             AND code IN (SELECT code
                                 FROM @codes);
PRINT '"L01": ' + cast(@L01 AS varchar(15)) + ';';
```

Therefore it can be easily extended (which I guess is the reason behind your approach) by inserting more codes into the table variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `WHERE` clause that you intend to reuse in a variable, then execute dynamic SQL to combine your `WHERE` clause variable with any additional `WHERE` conditions that you have (e.g. `AND paydue > @databasedate`). Try something like this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql
    'SELECT whatever ' +
    'FROM whoever ' +
    @WhereClause + -- Your @PersonalLoans variable(?)
    'AND paydue > ' + @databasedate
```

Comment: This approach has SQL injection attack written all over it!

Comment: @Blythmeister That's silly. Maybe if he were inserting user inputs into his WHERE clause, but he's using a hard-coded list that's defined wholly in the store procedure itself. No SQL injection here.

Comment: In the scope of this, maybe. But it's generally considered bad practice to do this.  In addition, this approach is very hard for any query analyser to comprehend, using a join to a table or an in statement is a far more acceptable and correct solution.